# How to read request body from Angular4 cli proxy?

Tags: angular, post, proxy, command-line-interface

I've configured my Angular4 CLI proxy and am posting a JSON object from my client side to the proxy which then calls my microservice. My microservice is not showing any attributes on the JSON object.

Is there a way that I can configure the CLI proxy to show me the req.body?

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md